# @media screen and Заставить работать в ie8

Tags: css3, html, css

Подскажите как заставить работать масштабирование в ie8. Встречал на хабре инструцию - но там написано что он работает только в ie9, хотя если открыть любую тему на themeforest, то в 8 они там работают прекрасно, как собственно мне сделать что бы мой сайт тоже масштабировался как мне нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подключаете [css3 mediaqueries](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) и все

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond